# Get relationships between direct and indirect instances a class?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I have a class named WeatherPatterns, it has many subclasses and the subclasses have named Individuals/ Instances.

I want a sparql query to retrieve all instances of WeatherPatterns that have relation with each other. For example, the output triples should be listed like the following.

```
Cloud produces Rain
Rain causes Flood
```

How to make this query? thanks in advance

Comment: "subclasses/instances of WeatherPatterns that have relation with each other" subclasses and instances are not the the same thing. And typically only instances have relationships between them; classes don't. How, in your data, are you saying that "cloud produces rain"? Without an example of your data, we can't write a query that retrieves information from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your data, we can't make an exact query, but if you're looking for relationships between things that are direct or indirect instances of **WeatherPatterns**, that's not too hard:

```sql
select ?s ?p ?o {
  #-- Make sure that ?s and ?o are
  #-- instance of WeatherPatterns
  #-- or its subclasses.
  ?s a/rdfs:subClassOf* :WeatherPatterns .
  ?o a/rdfs:subClassOf* :WeatherPatterns .

  #-- Find relationships between
  #-- ?s and ?o.
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

The property path **?s a/rdfs:subClassOf* :WeatherPatterns** uses **a** as the standard abbreviation for **rdf:type**, and matches when **?s** belongs to a class that is related by a chain of **rdfs:subClassOf** properties to **:WeatherPatterns**.  (The chain can be of length zero, which means that **?s** is a direct instance of **:WeatherPatterns**.)  If you want to combine the two checks into one, you can also do:

```
:WeatherPatterns ^(a/rdfs:subClassOf*) ?s, ?o .
```